# PostgreSQL function to insert into tables.. i need it to return specific values on errors and on specific if conditions

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, function, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  sp_process_ticket_block_receipt(receipt_id INTEGER, OUT status VARCHAR, OUT message VARCHAR)

AS $$ 
DECLARE     
  header record;
  detail_list record;
  boo boolean; 
BEGIN   
    SELECT * INTO header FROM ticket_block_receipt WHERE id = receipt_id;   
    FOR detail_list IN(SELECT * FROM ticket_block_receipt_detail WHERE ticket_block_receipt_id = receipt_id)        LOOP

     /* A insert Query here */
    select  INTO boo sp_save_ticket_stock_cost_centre(5); // function which returns true or false

    IF boo = false THEN
    /* here transaction should Rollback current changes and also should return a proper error message */
     END IF;
     END LOOP;
     status = 'success';
     message = 'Success message';

END; $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

> function which is used inside For loop above

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  sp_save_ticket_stock_cost_centre(receipt_detail_id INTEGER)

RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE 
    detail_list record;


BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO detail_list FROM ticket_block_receipt_detail WHERE id = receipt_detail_id;
    counter := detail_list.no_of_blocks;


    LOOP 
        EXIT WHEN counter = 0 ; 

        /* Insert Query here */

        counter := counter - 1 ;

    END LOOP ;

    RETURN TRUE;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE; 

END; $$
```

so... basic question is how can I RollBack with proper output
if this is not possible i am ok with suggestions..

i need to RollBack inside IF condition (IF boo = false THEN) which is based on another function which returns true or false..

i am going to use this in Spring project, with JPA and Hibernate.

please ask questions,  i am not able explain to my self here..

Comment: Could you a) format your code to be readable and b) describe more clearly what your problem is?

Comment: those tables are huge! Maybe you should considre to split them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you think about something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  sp_process_ticket_block_receipt(receipt_id INTEGER, OUT status VARCHAR, OUT message VARCHAR) AS $sql$
DECLARE
    res bool;
BEGIN
WITH detail_list AS (
    SELECT tbr.r,
           tbrd.*
      FROM ticket_block_receipt AS tbr
      JOIN ticket_block_receipt_detail AS tbrd ON (ticket_block_receipt_id = tbr.id)
     WHERE tbr.id = receipt_id
), inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO for_insert (ticket_block_receipt_id, cnt, calc)
    SELECT ticket_block_receipt_id, i, i * r
    FROM detail_list JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, detail_list.no_of_blocks) AS i ON true 
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT count(*) = (SELECT no_of_blocks FROM detail_list) INTO res
FROM inserted
;

IF RES THEN
    status = 'success';
    message = 'Success message';
    RETURN;
END IF;

RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error!!!';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    status = 'error';
    message = 'Error message';

END;
$sql$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT sp_process_ticket_block_receipt(1);
```

But looks like you can just use pure sql:

```
WITH detail_list AS (
    SELECT tbr.r,
           tbrd.*
      FROM ticket_block_receipt AS tbr
      JOIN ticket_block_receipt_detail AS tbrd ON (ticket_block_receipt_id = tbr.id)
     WHERE tbr.id = :receipt_id
), inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO for_insert (ticket_block_receipt_id, cnt, calc)
    SELECT ticket_block_receipt_id, i, i * r
    FROM detail_list JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, detail_list.no_of_blocks) AS i ON true 
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT count(*) = (SELECT no_of_blocks FROM detail_list)
FROM inserted;
```